# Load textures while playing

Tags: c#, xna

For my 2D game :
While playing, I have to load some large texture2D (2000x2500 pixels) and Unload some others.
Of course I want to Load and Unload texture2D without game/draw freeze (or the lesser...) :x
I don't know if it's possible.

I already use a thread to load some texture while drawing the "Loading screen"

```
//thread Loading
ThreadStart th_loadingScreen = delegate { DisplayLoading(LoadingScreen); };
new Thread(th_loadingScreen).Start();
```

But I think it's pretty different.

Of course, I tried something :

```
private void LoadUnload()
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= NbrRow; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i <= NbrCol; i++)
        {
            if(somethingTrue)
            {
                ThreadStart th_LoadInGame = delegate
                    {
                        LoadInGame(i, j, TextureStringPathToLoad);
                    };
                new Thread(th_LoadInGame).Start();
            }
        }
}
```

But I have a little freeze.

And, I know how to unload the content, but I don't know how to unload a single loaded texture :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to unload individual elements within a `ContentManager` object. So, what I do is make multiple `ContentManager`s and split up what I need to among them. That way I can `Unload` one, for example, and keep others in memory still.

As for the little freeze you're seeing, threading by itself does not guarantee an absence of hiccups or the like. I would mess around with the `Thread`'s [`Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) property; perhaps try setting it lower and see what happens. Even this is no guarantee however. From the article:

> Operating systems are not required to honor the priority of a thread.

Comment: I give you points because you answered my thread issue and I'll make another topic about the Unloading thing (because I have more questions about it and if someone answers me, I don't know who have to gain points). Thread's priority plus lower the textures' size did the job. Thx for the help !

Comment: [Here is the answer about Unload() a Texture2D](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970682/1456533)