# Unload the texture2D that I want to Unload

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I would like to Unload some Texture2D without Unloading everything.

Should I create a ContentManager for each Texture2D that I'm supposed to Unload later ?
These Texture2D don't have to be Unloaded at the same time)

There's something I didn't understand but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes... although I suspect you may want to opt for groups of textures per content manager instead. e.g. all the textures for a given level / scene etc.

Comment: Can I create a `ContentManager[]` maybe ? Can they share the same content.pipeline (not sure if it's its name) ? I mean : `ContentManager content, contentA, contentB, contentC;` and then in the `loadContent` => `content = contentA = contentB = contentC = Content;` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but here's my guess at answering: You can create an array of content managers although I suspect you may wish to, instead, have a class for each level / stage that has a content manager as a property. Each content manager will need to be created (as the example you gave would have an array of references to the same manager).As for loading, you need to call each contentManager's Load method for each texture you wish to load (i.e. there's no built in way to ask that a collection of content managers all load the same texture at once)

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed. Thx a lot lzcd